# Change an xml node name in ESB

Tags: xslt, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I want to change an xml node name in WSO2 ESB, ie. I have the following xml

`<MessageStatus xmlns="foo.example.org">

   <ErrorCode>$1</ErrorCode>

   <Message>$2</Message>

</MessageStatus>`

and I want it to be this

`<ItemName xmlns="foo.example.org">

   <ErrorCode>$1</ErrorCode>

   <Message>$2</Message>

</ItemName>`

With ItemNames as a property; I mean they would change dynamically.
Is there any way that I do this changes using ESB Mediators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I did this using XSLT Mediator, My Mediator config is like this:

```
<xslt xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" key="conf:/users/UsersXSLT.xslt">
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="TagName" expression="concat(get-property('OperationName'),'Response')"/>
</xslt>
```

which I defined a property for it that I can use it in my XSLT transformation.
My XSLT is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions"
xmlns="http://www.jdnasir.ac.ir/EMI/UserProxy/"
exclude-result-prefixes="fn">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:param name="TagName"/>
<xsl:template match="MessageStatus">
<xsl:element name="{$TagName}" xmlns="http://www.jdnasir.ac.ir/EMI/UserProxy/">
<xsl:for-each select="/MessageStatus/*">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The tricky part of this xslt was the `<xsl:element name="{$TagName}"` part.

I hope this would help others.